# Ошибка TypeError: cyclic object value

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть объект OBJ, когда делаю так:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(OBJ));
```

выдает такую ошибку TypeError: cyclic object value , от чего такая ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Похоже что если в объекте есть ссылка на html (obj.html) то такая ошибка выходит, я их убрал сработал

Answer (score 2):

Эта ошибка означает,что в одном из значений объекта имеется уже сериализованный объект, используйте в качестве второго параметра функцию для фильтрации. Пишу с планшета так что без кода)

Comment: понял, спасибо!